# Subscribe to an observable only if there are no other subscribers

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs

I have an HTTP server that emits events using rxjs. I filter my streams based on the request url like so

```
let stream = otherStream
   .filter(streams=>{
     return streams.req.url.match(/^\/api\//);
   });
```

How can I subscribe to the `stream` observable in such a way that the observable (`stream`) will only emit (to my subscriber) if there are no other subscribers? If the request matches my filter then I can call the respective `write`/`end` methods of the response but if there are no subscribers for a particular url, i.e. a `404` then I want to respond appropriately. Instead the connection just hangs because there are no subscribers registered to deal with the http response stream.

something like

```
let stream404 = otherStream
  .noSubscribers(streams=>{
    streams.res.statusCode = 404;
    streams.res.write('not found');
    streams.res.end();
  });
```

Comment: I need clarification about the code you gave. Is 'streams' a variable you have outside, hence let stream = otherStream.filter(() => streams.filter((stream) => <matches url> )) or do the streams come from the observable, in which case let stream = otherStream.filter((stream) => <match url> )) ?